# system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox does not contain the definition of "lines"

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to count repeated words from a text file and i am getting this error:

> system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox does not contain the definition of "lines"...

As far I remember the namespace for .lines is `system.windows.forms`... and I had already used it... So if anyone can guide me where I am going wrong...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Lines =File.ReadAllLines("D:\\mun.txt")
        Regex regex = new Regex("\\w+");

        var frequencyList = regex.Matches(TextBox1.Text)
                                 .Cast<Match>()
                                 .Select(c => c.Value.ToLowerInvariant())
                                 .GroupBy(c => c)
                                 .Select(g => new { Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                                 .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count)
                                 .ThenBy(g => g.Word);

        Dictionary<string, int> dict = frequencyList.ToDictionary(d => d.Word, d => d.Count);

        foreach (var item in frequencyList)
        {
            Label1.Text =Label1.Text+item.Word+"\n";
            Label2.Text = Label2.Text+item.Count.ToString()+"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is because your `TextBox` is under using `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace. The error is saying the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rows instead of Lines. You need the length of the array you read to set the Rows property. Since you've started with ReadAllLines, you need to build back the whole content, by contactenating the lines in a single string. HTML is using `<br />` to display a new line

```
protected void Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\mun.txt");
    var content = String.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, lines);
    TextBox1.Rows = lines.Length;
    TextBox1.Text = content;

    Regex regex = new Regex("\\w+");
    var frequencyList = regex.Matches(content)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(c => c.Value.ToLowerInvariant())
        .GroupBy(c => c)
        .Select(g => new { Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count)
        .ThenBy(g => g.Word);
    Dictionary<string, int> dict = frequencyList.ToDictionary(d => d.Word, d => d.Count);

    foreach (var item in frequencyList)
    {
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + item.Word + "<br />";
        Label2.Text = Label2.Text + item.Count.ToString() + "<br />";
    }
}
```